# Ionic run on device not working - daemon issue

Tags: ionic-framework, daemon

It was working find, however now I'm getting the below error, when I run this command:

`ionic run android`

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
adb I  3000 58815 usb_osx.cpp:259] Found vid=04e8 pid=6860 serial=41007659c88da12f
adb I  3000 58815 usb_osx.cpp:259] 
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: Got the same problem. I don't know it's the new ionic-beta-23's problem or not. After upgrade. I can't run any app in iOS and android emulator any more.